# Dynamic jquery dialog pop ups

Tags: jquery

I have only worked with a known number of JQuery dialogs and are having all sorts of trouble getting a dynamic version working.  Hopefully someone can help me with this.  here is how I do it with a known number:

```
$( "#opener1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );
    $( "#dialog1" ).height(200);
    return false;
});

$( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "fold",
    hide: "explode",
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    buttons: {
        Close: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

and then I do this:

```
<A HREF='' ID='opener1'>Text to open</a>

<div class="dialog1"> content here </div>
```

I would like to place both the  anchor tag and the div tag inside a loop (Classic ASP) and obviously dynamically name both the ID in the anchor tag and the class in the div.  Help would be very much appreciated.  Thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `href` attribute of the `a` tag to select the dialog to open.
This is a pattern applied by other jQuery UI modules like the tabs module.

It allows you to have multiple links for one dialog and a very readable way to link to the dialog content.

See the code in action <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WtK/1/)</kbd>

*javascript*

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(".dialog-opener").click(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
        show: "fold",
        hide: "explode",
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

html

```
<a href='#dialog1' class="dialog-opener">Text to open 1</a>
<a href='#dialog1' class="dialog-opener">Text to open 1</a>
<a href='#dialog2' class="dialog-opener">Text to open 2</a>

<div id="dialog1">Dialog 1</div>
<div id="dialog2">Dialog 2</div>
```