# Make jquery dialog pop up remain while parent/opener is being refreshed

Tags: jquery

I have a page which is being refreshed every 5 seconds using a meta refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=terminal.asp?x=<%= runningInterval %>" />
```

The page has multiple dynamically generated jQuery dialogs.  Thanks to the outstanding advice in this post: [Dynamic jquery dialog pop ups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647961/dynamic-jquery-dialog-pop-ups/17648026?iemail=1&noredirect=1#17648026)

My issue is when the dialog pops up it disappears by automatically when the parent refresh happens.  How can I force the dialog to remain regardless of what the parent/opener is doing?  I want the user to close the dialog when the wish.  Thanking you

Comment: You'll have to recreate the whole "parent" page "by hand" or make it a frame (and the dialog be opened from outside the frame).

Comment: @acdcjunior  Frames have not gone through my head in years. Frames or iFrames, does it matter? DO you know will I be able to build frames/ iframes version of this where one of the pages that feeds a frame section has the meta refresh.  SO only this section refreshes?? Thanking you

Comment: I meant `iframe`s. I added an answer to picture what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dialog is just another element of the page, so it will go away if the current page goes away.

To implement that "persistent" dialog, you'll have to or **(1)** "repaint" the whole current page (except the dialog) through removing and re-creating HTML elements; or **(2)** setup an `iframe`, open the dialog in the parent and change the page in the `iframe`. -- As the first point is (hard but) straightforward, let me show an example of the second approach.

**[CHECK the DEMO FIDDLE here.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/acdcjunior/DM2LG/7/show/)** (click [here to open it in **edit mode**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/DM2LG/7/))

#### Explanation:

The **parent** page will have a hidden dialog (and possibly other stuff) and an **`iframe` that takes the whole page**:

```
<div id="dialog1" style="display:none;">Parent Dialog!</div>
<iframe src="http://my.iframe.address.com" height="100%"></iframe>
```

And a JavaScript to open the dialog (check [the **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/DM2LG/7/) for the complete example.):

```
function openDialog() { // called by the inner iframe
    $('#dialog1').dialog({ /*...*/ });
}
```

Now the `iframe` page can be a page like any other (that can be used as an `iframe`, of course). [Check the used demo page fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/bPr2d/7/) And it will call the **parent to open the dialog** before redirecting itself:

```
parent.openDialog(); // calls function on parent that will open a dialog
window.location.href = "http://www.imdb.com"; // and then redirects itself
```

As usual, when using `iframe`s, be aware of the same-origin policy.

Comment: Now that looks like a great solution,thank you for you time and effort.  I will use/implement this after lunch and let you know.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have been trying to alter this to work when I have multiple dynamically named dialogs but are having trouble. Can you see any reason for this to be problematic in this scenario?  EG you are using an onclick event which fires the open dialog in the parent which is called dialog1 - As seen in the example link in my initial post I am using  a href="#dialog[uniqueNumber]" class="dialog opener" and as I said are having a bit of trouble.

Comment: Maybe these will help: http://fiddle.jshell.net/acdcjunior/DM2LG/10/show/ - Edit links: **parent:** http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/DM2LG/10/  **iframe:** http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/bPr2d/9/

Comment: OK i just got it working but it has taken multiple functions (which you called stuff) on the inner iframe and also therefore multiple openDialog functions on the parent. I will post a response so I can briefly show you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the dialog is a child element inside the parent element, so refreshing the parent (e.g. clearing all children and re-populating) will remove the dialog.  You can't really fix this if you do it this way.  If it's possible, I would parent the dialog window to another element that isn't refreshed.

For example, directly in the document.

Comment: thank you for your time.  As you say 'if its possible' Do you have a bit more direction on parenting the dialog to another element?  Should I be thinking about ditching jQuery dialog?  I know opening a good ole javascript new window would stay there however the issue I see with this is that the child would loose focus and the parent would sit ontop when it refreshed.  Any one have an idea how I can achieve my objective? Thank in advance